# Phaser 3 Arcade: Setting Y of camera following player to fixed

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm started with a endless runner game, the player position is fixed and objects are moving to the left. I use `camera.startFollowing(player)` to follow the player but when I jump the camera moves with the player. But the camera Y position must be fixed.

Tried to set the offset by `setFollowOffset();` And I have tried to use the impact physics but Phaser can't find `this.impact`.
I use Phaser 3.

I have removed non-relevant code from the code snippet below.

```js
var player, ground, camera;
function create(){
   ground = this.physics.add.image(0, 568, 'ground').setScale(2, 2).setGravity(0);
   player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 510, 'dude');
   player.setBounce(0);
   ground.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
   this.physics.add.collider(ground, player);
   camera = this.cameras.main;
   camera.startFollow(player);
   camera.setFollowOffset(-300, 225);
}

function update(){
   if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
   {
      player.setVelocityY(-275);
   }  
}


var config = {
   type: Phaser.AUTO,
   width: 800,
   height: 600,
   backgroundColor: '#ffff9c',
   physics:{
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade:{
         gravity: {y: 600},
         debug: false,
      }
   },
   scene:{
      preload: preload,
      create: create,
      update: update
   }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I add:

```js
camera.setLerp(0,0);
```